# How can I hide a double scroll bar?

Tags: scroll, scrollbar

I have a script and installed it on a [Hostinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostinger) server. When accessing my site, I see a long, green scroll bar:

[Double scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K39MT.png)

How can I fix it?

This is my CSS content:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gIPsDhyvUPZ11RcStUEl_1B6G7lKUy5/view?usp=sharing

Note:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I tried this code and it was solved, but it’s hiding the last part of the footer (created by Otlobli ✍️ أطلبلي).

[This is before the edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TOmV.png)

[This is after edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRCgn.png)

I need to solve it without losing this line (created by Otlobli ✍️ أطلبلي).